# What is the point of confessing before the meal on Erev Yom Kippur according to the Rambam?

Tags: rambam, yom-kippur, mishneh-torah, viduy-confession

The Rambam (Hilchos Teshuvah 2:7) writes that the reason why one should recite the Vidui on Erev Yom Kippur before the meal is that he might choke (heaven forbid) during the meal.

The question is: if he dies (heaven forbid) before the onset of Yom Kippur, what does his confession help, being that seemingly one needs to be in this world in order for Yom Kippur to atone for him? (See the Binyan Yehoshua on Avos De’Rabbi Nosson (25:5), that it is for this reason that it is considered a negative sign for one to passes away on Erev Yom Kippur)

Comment: See the שפת אמת יומא פ"א עמוד ב, where he postulates that כל האוכל ושותה בתשיעי מעלה עליו הכתוב כאילו התענה תשיעי ועשירי, makes it considered by mincha like vidui on Yom Kippur. https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14522&st=&pgnum=123&hilite=  the last paragraph going on to the next page

Comment: @אילפא, Yasher Koach, this seems like a great  explanation!